# Action method to export excel and prevent user from reprocessing the action till complete

Tags: java, excel, struts2, export, action

I'm trying to write an Action method to export an excel and at the same time prevent the user from recalling the action while processing.

The problem is that when I re-click on the submit (export) the content of the excel to be exported is displayed on the web page and when the export is completed, i have this exception :

```
rg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path     [/myApp] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /decorators/main.jsp at line 48
```

I used this code for my action method :

```
@Action(value = "exportExcelMdt", results = {

        @Result(name = "exportExcel", 
                type = "stream", 
              params = { "inputName", "inputStream", 
                       "contentType", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
                "contentDisposition", "attachment;filename=${filename};", 
                        "bufferSize", "1024" }),

        @Result(name = "success", 
                type = ActionSupport.NONE) 
})

public String doExportExcel() {

    Boolean exportPending = (Boolean) this.session.get(EXPORT_EXCEL);
    if (exportPending == null) { // this is used as a semaphore to prevent the user from re-calling the export action (server-side of course)
        try {
            this.session.put(EXPORT_EXCEL, Boolean.TRUE);
            logger.debug("export excel...");
            this.filename = this.getText("myApp.message.mandat.recherche.extraction.filename");
            this.inputStream = this.extractExcel(this.searchResults(false)); // this will just get the related beans and write the excel file using Apache POI
            return "exportExcel";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("export excel erreur...");
        } finally {
            this.session.remove(EXPORT_EXCEL);
        }
    } else {
        //          this.addActionMessage("An export excel is already running !");
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

JSP code to call the action :

```jsp
function insertExcelButtonForExtraction() {
    // creer le nom depuis "#gview_" + l'id de la grid  
    var $btnExcel = $('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel');

    // Check if object already exists 
    if(!$btnExcel.length) {
        var $a = $('#gview_resultGrid > div > a');
        var $newA = $a.clone();

        $newA.attr('style', 'right: 25px; padding-top: 2px;');
        $newA.attr('id', 'btnExcel');
        $newA.children("span").remove();
        $newA.append($('<input id="searchForm_exportExcelMdt" type="image" onclick="exportExcel();" src="/myApp/img/page_white_excel.png" title="<s:text name="myApp.message.js.button.excelExtraction"/>"/>'));
        $newA.insertAfter($a);
    }
}

// export excel
function exportExcel() {  
    $("#searchForm").attr("action", "exportExcelMdt.action");
    $("#searchForm").submit();
}
```

Here is the related struts.xml file :

```xml
<struts>
<constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/jsp/" />
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="app-pkg" />
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="${struts.mode}" />
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="ihm,actions" />
<!--    <constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="" /> -->
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10000000" />

<package name="app-pkg" extends="json-default,struts-default">

    <interceptors>

        <interceptor name="exception" 
          class="amundi.sits.sigma.web.utils.interceptor.ExceptionLoggingInterceptor" />

        <interceptor name="i18n"
          class="amundi.sits.sigma.web.utils.interceptor.I18nInterceptor" />                

        <!-- Basic Stack -->
        <interceptor-stack name="appBasicStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception">
                <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
                <param name="logLevel">ERROR</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare">
                <param name="excludeMethods">search*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="multiselect" />
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor-stack name="appStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="appBasicStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation" />
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>

        <interceptor-stack name="annotatedStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <interceptor-ref name="annotationWorkflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>


        <!-- Stack basique qui priorise les params sur le prepare -->
        <interceptor-stack name="paramsFirstStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n" />
            <interceptor-ref name="exception">
                <param name="logEnabled">true</param>
                <param name="logLevel">ERROR</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams" />
        </interceptor-stack>

        <!-- Stack Json validation -->

        <interceptor-stack name="jsonValidationStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="appBasicStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidation" />
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow" />
        </interceptor-stack>

    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="appStack" />

    <global-results>
        <result name="exception">/jsp/view/error/error.jsp</result>
        <result name="login" type="redirect">/Login.action</result>
        <result name="accessdenied" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">security/access/accessDenied.action</param>
            <param name="namespace">/</param>
        </result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Throwable"
            result="exception" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

</package>
```

Comment: Is it rendered normally first time?

Comment: We need more code, struts.xml, action definition, jsp snippet... tricky question btw

Comment: @RomanC : Yes, if i click only one time it is rendered normally and i get my excel file to download.
@ Andrea Ligios : I added more informations (jsp, struts.xml and some details about the action). Please take a look when you have the time to and let me know what you think about it.

Comment: `name = "success", type = ActionSupport.NONE` looks a bit odd. Just return `none`.

Comment: Already did that :D The constant is equal to "none" and its the same result :(

Comment: But you're using it in `type`. See http://struts.apache.org/docs/result-configuration.html.

Comment: Your jQuery part is quite weird: an <a> with an <input> inside that performs a form submit (that returns stream or none). It might have something to do with event bubbling and the missing *prevent default*. Try creating a simple button with no <a> around. Also consider that this selector `$('#gview_resultGrid > div > #btnExcel');` is overly complicated, because since **id** is unique, `$('#btnExcel');` is enough.

Comment: Yes you are absolutly right ! but this is old code .. I can't (only in last resort) modify that. 
I think i am gonna think about this on client-side. (i'll probably post a new question because i can't figure out how to chain synchronous calls to execute the export and reshow the hidden button)

Answer (score 0):

The [execute and wait interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html) seems to provide what you need

Comment: I did look at this, the problem is that i need to stay on the same page and have something that is loading (a popup ; gif maybe) and when finished it should just display a popup saying done.
i think i should consider a client-side solution ..