# Perform an struts action and prevent the user from reprocessing until done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i posted a question earlier about the export of an excel file with a control server-side to prevent the user from recalling the action ([Action method to export excel and prevent user from reprocessing the action till complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998339/action-method-to-export-excel-and-prevent-user-from-reprocessing-the-action-till)) ! 
One fellah suggested to used Execute and Wait Interceptor (Struts) which is a very good way to handle long-processing in backgroung !

But, the problem is that i need to stay on the page from where i did the export so that the user can interact with it (he just can't export until the export is done) :

So i found out a solution to do it client side with this :

```
function handler() {
    $("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").attr("disabled", false);
}
// export excel
function exportExcel() {
    console.log("toto is exporting ..");
    $("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").attr("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
                method : "GET",
                url : "/myApp/view/mandat/recherche/doNothing.action",
                traditional : true,
                success : function(data) {
                    $(location).load('exportExcelMdt.action',handler).attr('href','exportExcelMdt.action');
                }
            });
}
```

So this basically will disable the button, call the action "doNothing()" that just returns success. Then the action exportExcelMdt (export the file) will be called before the handler that re-activates the button and finnally i recall the current page (similar to refresh) to force the file to be downloaded (not sure about that but without it no file is generated).

So this worked on Chrome, IE but not on Firefox !!!! :'(

Even the error is not displayed in the console, i am just redirected to my error page.

If anyone knows what would be the cause of this or how to deactivate the input for Firefox that would be very helpful !

PS : You can find the JSP, Struts.xml, Action's description on the link on the previous thread.

Comment: This is not a java question, but a javascript and html question, so I change the tags

Comment: Yes sorry about that! So used to ask java questions lol thanks for the edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").attr("disabled", true);
```

and

```
$("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").attr("disabled", false);
```

use

```
// Use disabled string as attribute instead of true
$("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

and

```
// remove attribute instead of set it to false
$("#searchForm_exportExcelMdt").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Still the same error with firefox :'( 
« none », URL, ou function filter expected, but « progid » found.  Analysis error for the value « filter ».  Déclaration aborted hope you understand it.

sorry i have translated the message from french.